# How to interpolate javascript into html within javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to interpolate a variable into html that is within a javascript file.
I thought it would be simple but i cant seem to find the correct way.
From the code below, i want to interpolate the 'number' variable into the html, data_id.
thanks.

```html
        var  number = 1
var html = ['<input type="text" id="search_name_1" data_id= name class="form-control add-member-on-policy-search"/>',
        '<div class="ellipsis-overflow">'
        ].join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template string.  Use the backtick ``` instead of a quote '.  Then you can input variables into the string using the `${your variable}` syntax:

```
var  number = 1
var html = [`<input type="text" id="search_name_1" data_id=${number} class="form-control add-member-on-policy-search"/>`,
        `<div class="ellipsis-overflow">`
        ].join('');
```